# Where is Particle Velocity and Rotation in Blender 2.7a?

Tags: particles

I'm trying to make some Grass in Blender 2.7a but, I can't seem to find the Velocity in the Hair emitter settings, nor the Rotation, I use these to add random Velocity and rotation to my grass, can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Velocity is a setting category for both emitter and hair types of particles. If you are using the *hair* type of particles, click on the *advanced* check mark (Under the *type* drop down box). If you are using the *emitter* type then you should see it by default.

For random looking grass, I would recommend you use *Brownian* under the Physics category then *Newtonian* type.